# SQL Query to get oldest date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL and have a large database that contains IDs and Service Dates and I need to write a query to give me the first date each ID had a service.

I tried:

```
SELECT dbo.table.ID, dbo.otherTable.ServiceDate AS EasliestDate
FROM dbo.table INNER JOIN dbo.table.ID = dbo.otherTable.ID
```

But the output is every service for every ID, which has too many results to sort through. I want the output to only show the ID and the oldest service date. Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT: To be more precise, the output I am looking for is the ID and service date if the oldest service date is during the year that I specify. I.E. if  ID = 1 has a service in 2015 and 2016 and I am searching for IDs in 2016 then ID = 1 should not appear in the results because there was an earlier service in 2015.

EDIT: Thanks everyone who helped with this! The answer I accepted did exactly what I asked. Major kudos to Patty though who who elaborated on how to further filter the outcome by year.

Comment: In general you don't really need to qualify the table name out the `from` clause. So you really should get rid of the `dbo.` everywhere else.

Comment: @shawnt00 Microsoft SQL Server management Studio is automatically adding the dbo. portion whenever I use the table name.

Comment: I guess that doesn't surprise me but it isn't really the best form. You might consider looking into aliases (aka correlation names).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and [`MIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms179916.aspx) to get the first date for each ID:

```
SELECT  dbo.table.ID, 
        MIN(dbo.otherTable.ServiceDate) AS EasliestDate
FROM    dbo.table 
        INNER JOIN otherTable 
            ON dbo.table.ID = dbo.otherTable.ID
GROUP BY dbo.table.ID;
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

In reference to a question in the comments:

> how would I also restrict it to show only those who had a service in a specific year?

It would depend on your exact requirements, consider the following set:

```
ID      ServiceDate
--------------------
1       2014-05-01
1       2015-08-01
1       2016-07-07
2       2015-08-19
```

You would only want to include ID = 1 if the year you specified was 2016, but assuming you still wanted to return the first date of `2014-05-01` then you would need to add a having clause with a case statement to get this.

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2016;

DECLARE @YearStart DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900, '19000101'),
        @YearEnd DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900 + 1, '19000101');

SELECT @YearStart, @YearEnd

SELECT  t.ID, 
        MIN(o.ServiceDate) AS EasliestDate
FROM    dbo.table AS t
        INNER JOIN otherTable AS o
            ON o.ID = r.ID
GROUP BY t.ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN o.ServiceDate >= @YearStart 
                    AND o.ServiceDate < @YearEnd THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

If you only want the earliest date in 2016 the a where clause would suffice

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2016;

DECLARE @YearStart DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900, '19000101'),
        @YearEnd DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900 + 1, '19000101');

SELECT @YearStart, @YearEnd

SELECT  t.ID, 
        MIN(o.ServiceDate) AS EasliestDate
FROM    dbo.table AS t
        INNER JOIN otherTable AS o
            ON o.ID = r.ID
WHERE   o.ServiceDate >= @YearStart 
AND     o.ServiceDate < @YearEnd 
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

It is worth noting there is a very good reason I have chosen to calculate the start of the year, and the start of the next year and used

```
WHERE   o.ServiceDate >= @YearStart 
AND     o.ServiceDate < @YearEnd
```

Instead of just

```
WHERE   DATEPART(YEAR, o.ServiceDate) = 2016;
```

In the former, an index on `ServiceDate` can be used whereas in the latter, the `DATEPART` calculation must be done on every record and this can cause significant performace issues.

**ADDENDUM 2**

To do the following:

> The exact thing I want then would be IDs who's earliest service is in the year I specify.

Then you would need a having clause, just a different one to the one I posted before:

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2016;

DECLARE @YearStart DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900, '19000101'),
        @YearEnd DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900 + 1, '19000101');

SELECT @YearStart, @YearEnd

SELECT  t.ID, 
        MIN(o.ServiceDate) AS EasliestDate
FROM    dbo.table AS t
        INNER JOIN otherTable AS o
            ON o.ID = r.ID
GROUP BY t.ID
HAVING  MIN(o.ServiceDate) >= @YearStart 
AND     MIN(o.ServiceDate) < @YearEnd;
```

**ADDENDUM 3**

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
AS
    SELECT  dbo.table.ID, 
            MIN(dbo.otherTable.ServiceDate) AS EasliestDate
    FROM    dbo.table 
            INNER JOIN otherTable 
                ON dbo.table.ID = dbo.otherTable.ID
    GROUP BY dbo.table.ID;
```

Then you can apply your criteria to the view:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.YourView
WHERE   EasliestDate >= '2015-01-01'
AND     EasliestDate < '2016-01-01';
```

Comment: Awesome! This works great. Although it wasn't in my question, how would I also restrict it to show only those who had a service in a specific year? Would I add a "WHERE dbo.otherTable.serviceDate >= YYYY - MM - DD AND < YYYY+1 - MM - DD" statement before the group by?

Comment: @CSJunkie Can the earliest service date fall outside that year or are you only interested in service with the specific year?

Comment: @shawnt00 I'm attempting to find out when each ID was entered into my system but as that information was not always recorded by data entry I'm using the earliest service date as an estimate. Patty showed how to filter this information below. Thanks for asking though :)

Comment: @CSJunkie Ok, just be aware there is a difference in asking for the earliest of services within a window and earliest service with at least one service within the window.

Comment: @shawnt00 The exact thing I want then would be IDs who's earliest service is in the year I specify.

Comment: @GarethD This is working but it will not let me save this as a view. The error message states "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE' and then closes the save option without saving. I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include a WHERE in your current query:

```
SELECT dbo.table.ID, dbo.otherTable.ServiceDate AS EasliestDate
FROM dbo.table INNER JOIN dbo.table.ID = dbo.otherTable.ID
WHERE Month(dbo.otherTable.ServiceDate) = 1
```

Or you can search with Year(dbo.otherTable.ServiceDate) = 2016
Or you can use Day(dbo.otherTable.ServiceDate) = 1

Or an specific date.

Comment: Or you can use a "Order by" statement.

Answer (score 1):

use [group by](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) and [min](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-min-function.htm) to get records. Else you can refer http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a "Group by" statement.  Try this:
`SELECT dbo.table.ID, Max(dbo.otherTable.ServiceDate) AS LatestDate, Min(dbo.otherTable.ServiceDate as EarliestDate)
FROM dbo.table INNER JOIN dbo.table.ID = dbo.otherTable.ID
group by dbo.table.ID`

Answer (score 0):

Use nested statement to get the min date , and then just match based on ID.

```
select t1.ID from table1 t1  INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT ID, MIN(servicedate) MinServiceDate
         FROM table2
         GROUP BY ID
       ) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```